# compare quick deployment,learning curve and future scope of: PHP vs RUBY vs.NET platform

Tags: php, .net, ruby-on-rails, comparison, scope

I'm mainly asking that, although php was behind facebook success, but is the other mentioned platforms are small with respect to php.
So, please try to give me some comparision of the technologies you used from above three for small as well as enterprise development.
And which should I learn in order to serve larger audience.and for more free community support and deployment cost.
Thankyou for your time to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google will help:

- http://www.cmswire.com/cms/industry-news/php-vs-java-vs-ruby-000887.php : PHP vs. Java vs Ruby ( you can ignore the Java as it wasn't your request )  .. 2006!
- http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/language-war-php-vs-ruby-2/ : PHP Vs Ruby March 3, 2011

It really comes down to your aptitude, willingness to learn, history that you have in programming and the examples that are out there.

There is no right answer to this question ...

It comes down to the person.  I would suggest PHP, only because of LAMP .. Linux Apache MySQL PHP ... it is widely adopted and a lot of examples and code.  I am sure the same is true for RoR and .NET ...

Comment: thank you man, i gone through the second option, and i realized that , ruby is for experienced programmers and php is for me, who needs to learn lower level detail, how web works .